# Is ECHILD generated by a call to system(3) a failure?

Tags: c++, embedded, cross-platform

I'm currently working on a C++ server that takes requests and spawns off new processes to handle them. Those child processes then (sometimes) have to execute calls to system(3) to invoke other programs (third party ones over which I have no control). This server is being ported over to a new hardware platform, so I have to retain compatibility between multiple systems, going back to kernel 2.4.20. I'm currently ignoring children (signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN)) and this works fine on the old kernel, however when I run the server on the newer kernels to which I'm porting the server (2.6, 3.2) on different hardware, this system call fails, with system(3) setting errno to ECHILD. What's changed in the kernel and what's the proper way of handling children if I can't ignore them ? (Note, when I register a handler for SIGCHLD following Beej's example, it works fine)

Comment: Don't spawn new processes with `system`. You're in for a world of pain.

Comment: Hah! You haven't been on this project. I have no choice (believe me, I don't want to use system(3), but I really don't have any other choice, unless you can think of a better way to invoke a third-party tool). There have been arguments. The issue's been discussed to death.